# Can Crystal Reports be controlled via url access?

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I'd like to know whether crystal reports allows url access to render reports? I know we can create webpages that host a reportviewer object. However, I plan on using C# windows service to access the report, i.e. through a url.

The report I wish to generate needs to be in MHTML/HTML and PDF format. So if I could do something that URL access that [RSSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153586.aspx) can do, with Crystal Reports. That would help immensely.

Regards,
Shameegh

Answer (score 1):

If you report has been deployed to BusinessObjects Enterprise, you can use [Url Reporting](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/BusinessObjectsXIR2/en/en/BOE_SDK/boesdk_java_dg_doc/doc/boesdk_java_dg/Report_Linking.html).  If not, you will need to write your own interface.

If you write your own interface, base it on the Url Reporting interface and add the project to code.google.com. ;)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Reporting Services allows you to access reports via a URL. You can select various options for the report (Excel, PDF, etc...). Then just have a hyperlink on your page to pass parameters or use as a web service behind the scenes. You could have the same report show PDF or HTML based upon the query string option.

To learn more about Reporting Services see: http://alexduggleby.com/2008/07/18/sql-server-reporting-services-2008-tutorial-in-5-minutes-or-how-to-send-my-boss-a-report-from-a-view-quickly/